# Try to show text in different language

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have set a cookie named 'lang'. It will be assigned with a value by the current language while browsing. But how can I show a text in the current language?

Comment: echo $_COOKIE["lang"]; not working ???

Comment: PHP 5.3 has native i18n support. See http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
if($_COOKIE["lang"]=='dutch'){
$text='dutch text';
}
elseif($_COOKIE["lang"]=='german'){
$text='german text';
}
elseif($_COOKIE["lang"]=='french'){
$text='french text';
}

echo $text;
```